# curl ignore --data starting with @ sign: don't read from file

Tags: http, curl

In [slack](http://slack.com) you can script slackbot to post messages to a channel like this:

```
curl --data "$msg" $'https://<yourteam>.slack.com/services/hooks/slackbot?token=<yourtoken>&channel=#random'
```

Now i'd like to mention a username as the first part of the message like `msg="@joernhees hello self"`.

The problem with this is that if the `--data` argument of curl starts with an `@` sign it will interpret the string after the `@` as filename and post its content. Is there a way to make curl ignore the `@` sign and to send a literal `@` as the first char of a post request?

Answer (score 1):

Actually i just found out i can do this (not sure it's the best option though):

```
curl --data '@-' $'https://<yourteam>.slack.com/services/hooks/slackbot?token=<yourtoken>&channel=#random' <<< "$msg"
```

The trick is to tell curl to read from stdin `@-` and then pass the message in via that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and the fix turned out to be using `--data-raw` for normal situations (see https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-raw) or `--form-string` for multipart data (see https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--form-string).  Thus, here you would presumably use:

```
curl --data-raw "$msg" 'https://<yourteam>.slack.com/services/hooks/slackbot?token=<yourtoken>&channel=#random'
```